# Обработка запроса удаленно по выбору select

Tags: jquery, select

Друзья, помогите разобраться пожалуйста!
Пытаюсь разобраться с jquery, задача следующая: при выборе марки машины из селекта, в соседнем div появляется результат в виде второго селекта, где нужно выбрать модель. С помощью яндекспоиска, с миру по нитке получился вот такой кусок кода:

ps: сразу о проблеме, все работает, только после выбора марки селект блокируется и возможно выбрать только модель, а так быть не должно, помогите найти проблему, спасибо!

```js
$(function(){
    //Живой поиск
    $('.car').click(function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: "findcar.php", //Путь к обработчику
                data: {'car_referal':this.value},
                response: 'html',
                success: function(data){
                    $(".car_search_result").html(data); //Выводим полученые данные в списке
                }
            })
    })

})
```

выбор марки:

```html
<div style="float:left; display:inline-block;">
<select name="car_referal" size="1" class="car">
<option value="-----">-----</option><?php
$result_brands = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM brands ORDER BY brand_name");
while ($row_brands = mysql_fetch_array($result_brands)){
print "<option value='".$row_brands[brand_id]."'>".$row_brands[brand_name]."</option>";
}//while_brands
?></select>  </div>
<div style="position:relative; left:20px;" class="car_search_result"></div>
```

выбор модели (обрабатывается в файле findcar.php)

```html
<?
include('adm/connect.php');
if(!empty($_POST["car_referal"])){ //Принимаем данные
$referal = $_POST["car_referal"]; 
$result_service = mysql_query("select * from models where brand_id='$referal'");
?><select ><option value="-----">-----</option><?
while ($row_service = mysql_fetch_array($result_service)){
if ($car != '0'){
print "<option value='-----'>".$row_service[model_name]."</option</select><br>";
}
}
}
?>
```

итоговая страница

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


    <script>  
$(function(){
    //Живой поиск
    $('.car').click(function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: "findcar.php", //Путь к обработчику
                data: {'car_referal':this.value},
                response: 'html',
                success: function(data){
                    $(".car_search_result").html(data); //Выводим полученые данные в списке
                }
            })
                return false;  
$(".car").attr("disabled","");
    })

})
    </script>  

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/tabl.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/search.css">
</head><body>
    


<form method="post">
    <table width="633" border='1'>
        <tr>
            <td width="27%">ФИО</td>
            <td width="70%" align="left">
                <p><input type="text" name="fio"> - пример: Иванов Иван Иваныч</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="27%">Марка, модель</td>
            <td width="70%" align="left">

<div style="float:left; display:inline-block;">
<select name="car_referal" size="1" class="car">
<option value="-----">-----</option><option value='1'>AC</option><option value='2'>Acura</option><option value='3'>Alfa Romeo</option><option value='4'>Alpine</option><option value='5'>AM General</option><option value='6'>Ariel</option><option value='7'>Aro</option><option value='8'>Asia</option><option value='9'>Aston Martin</option><option value='10'>Audi</option><option value='11'>Austin</option><option value='12'>Autobianchi</option><option value='13'>Baltijas Dzips</option><option value='14'>Beijing</option><option value='15'>Bentley</option><option value='16'>Bertone</option><option value='17'>Bitter</option><option value='18'>BMW</option><option value='19'>BMW Alpina</option><option value='20'>Brabus</option><option value='21'>Brilliance</option><option value='22'>Bristol</option><option value='23'>Bufori</option><option value='24'>Bugatti</option><option value='25'>Buick</option><option value='26'>BYD</option><option value='27'>Byvin</option><option value='28'>Cadillac</option><option value='29'>Callaway</option><option value='30'>Carbodies</option><option value='31'>Caterham</option><option value='32'>Changan</option><option value='33'>ChangFeng</option><option value='34'>Chery</option><option value='35'>Chevrolet</option><option value='36'>Chrysler</option><option value='37'>Citroen</option><option value='38'>Cizeta</option><option value='39'>Coggiola</option><option value='40'>Dacia</option><option value='41'>Dadi</option><option value='42'>Daewoo</option><option value='43'>DAF</option><option value='44'>Daihatsu</option><option value='45'>Daimler</option><option value='46'>Dallas</option><option value='47'>Datsun</option><option value='48'>De Tomaso</option><option value='49'>DeLorean</option><option value='50'>Derways</option><option value='51'>Dodge</option><option value='52'>DongFeng</option><option value='53'>Doninvest</option><option value='54'>Donkervoort</option><option value='55'>E-Car</option><option value='56'>Eagle</option><option value='57'>Eagle Cars</option><option value='58'>Ecomotors</option><option value='59'>FAW</option><option value='60'>Ferrari</option><option value='61'>Fiat</option><option value='62'>Fisker</option><option value='63'>Ford</option><option value='64'>Foton</option><option value='65'>FSO</option><option value='66'>Fuqi</option><option value='67'>Geely</option><option value='68'>Geo</option><option value='69'>GMC</option><option value='70'>Gonow</option><option value='71'>Great Wall</option><option value='72'>Hafei</option><option value='73'>Haima</option><option value='282'>Hawtai</option><option value='74'>Hindustan</option><option value='75'>Holden</option><option value='76'>Honda</option><option value='77'>HuangHai</option><option value='78'>Hummer</option><option value='79'>Hyundai</option><option value='80'>Infiniti</option><option value='81'>Innocenti</option><option value='82'>Invicta</option><option value='83'>Iran Khodro</option><option value='84'>Isdera</option><option value='85'>Isuzu</option><option value='86'>IVECO</option><option value='87'>JAC</option><option value='88'>Jaguar</option><option value='89'>Jeep</option><option value='90'>Jensen</option><option value='91'>JMC</option><option value='92'>Kia</option><option value='93'>Koenigsegg</option><option value='94'>KTM</option><option value='95'>Lamborghini</option><option value='96'>Lancia</option><option value='97'>Land Rover</option><option value='98'>Landwind</option><option value='99'>Lexus</option><option value='100'>Liebao Motor</option><option value='101'>Lifan</option><option value='102'>Lincoln</option><option value='103'>Lotus</option><option value='104'>LTI</option><option value='105'>Luxgen</option><option value='106'>Mahindra</option><option value='107'>Marcos</option><option value='108'>Marlin</option><option value='109'>Marussia</option><option value='110'>Maruti</option><option value='111'>Maserati</option><option value='112'>Maybach</option><option value='113'>Mazda</option><option value='114'>McLaren</option><option value='115'>Mega</option><option value='116'>Mercedes-Benz</option><option value='117'>Mercury</option><option value='118'>Metrocab</option><option value='119'>MG</option><option value='120'>Microcar</option><option value='121'>Minelli</option><option value='122'>Mini</option><option value='123'>Mitsubishi</option><option value='124'>Mitsuoka</option><option value='125'>Morgan</option><option value='126'>Morris</option><option value='127'>Nissan</option><option value='128'>Noble</option><option value='129'>Oldsmobile</option><option value='130'>Opel</option><option value='131'>Osca</option><option value='132'>Pagani</option><option value='133'>Panoz</option><option value='134'>Perodua</option><option value='135'>Peugeot</option><option value='136'>Piaggio</option><option value='137'>Plymouth</option><option value='138'>Pontiac</option><option value='139'>Porsche</option><option value='140'>Premier</option><option value='141'>Proton</option><option value='142'>PUCH</option><option value='143'>Puma</option><option value='144'>Qoros</option><option value='145'>Qvale</option><option value='146'>Reliant</option><option value='147'>Renault</option><option value='148'>Renault Samsung</option><option value='149'>Rolls-Royce</option><option value='150'>Ronart</option><option value='151'>Rover</option><option value='152'>Saab</option><option value='153'>Saleen</option><option value='154'>Santana</option><option value='155'>Saturn</option><option value='156'>Scion</option><option value='157'>SEAT</option><option value='158'>ShuangHuan</option><option value='159'>Skoda</option><option value='160'>Smart</option><option value='161'>Soueast</option><option value='162'>Spectre</option><option value='163'>Spyker</option><option value='165'>Ssang Yong</option><option value='166'>Subaru</option><option value='167'>Suzuki</option><option value='168'>Talbot</option><option value='169'>TATA</option><option value='170'>Tatra</option><option value='171'>Tazzari</option><option value='172'>Tesla</option><option value='173'>Tianma</option><option value='174'>Tianye</option><option value='175'>Tofas</option><option value='176'>Toyota</option><option value='177'>Trabant</option><option value='178'>Tramontana</option><option value='179'>Triumph</option><option value='180'>TVR</option><option value='280'>Ultima</option><option value='181'>Vauxhall</option><option value='182'>Vector</option><option value='183'>Venturi</option><option value='184'>Volkswagen</option><option value='185'>Volvo</option><option value='186'>Vortex</option><option value='187'>Wartburg</option><option value='188'>Westfield</option><option value='189'>Wiesmann</option><option value='190'>Xin Kai</option><option value='191'>Zastava</option><option value='192'>Zotye</option><option value='193'>ZX</option><option value='212'>Автокам</option><option value='213'>Астро</option><option value='214'>Бронто</option><option value='215'>ВАЗ</option><option value='216'>ГАЗ</option><option value='211'>Ё-мобиль</option><option value='217'>ЗАЗ</option><option value='218'>ЗИЛ</option><option value='219'>ИЖ</option><option value='220'>КамАЗ</option><option value='221'>Канонир</option><option value='222'>ЛУАЗ</option><option value='223'>Москвич</option><option value='225'>СеАЗ</option><option value='224'>СМЗ</option><option value='226'>ТагАЗ</option><option value='227'>УАЗ</option></select>  </div>
<div style="position:relative; left:20px;" class="car_search_result"></div>

            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="27%">Гос.номер</td>
            <td width="70%" align="left">
                <p><input type="text" name="car_mod"> - пример: А222МР77</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="27%" height="14">Номер телефона</td>
            <td width="70%" height="14" align="left">
                <p><input type="text" name="tel"></p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="623" colspan="2">
                <p align="center"><b>-------------------------- АДРЕС --------------------------</b></p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="171" height="13">
                <p align="right">Улица:</p>
            </td>
            <td width="70%" height="13" align="left">
                <p><input type="text" name="street" size="33"></p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="27%" height="12">
                <p align="right">Дом</p>
            </td>
            <td width="70%" height="12" align="left">
                <p><input type="text" name="h_num" size="9"></p>
            </td>
        </tr>
          <tr>
            <td width="27%" height="12">
                <p align="right">Корпус</p>
            </td>
            <td width="70%" height="12" align="left">
                <p><input type="text" name="h_ko" size="9"></p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="27%" height="35">
                <p align="right">Квартира</p>
            </td>
            <td width="70%" height="35" align="left">
                <p><input type="text" name="h_kv" size="9"></p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="27%" height="23">
                <p align="right">Подъезд</p>
            </td>
            <td width="70%" height="23" align="left">
                <p><input type="text" name="h_pd" size="9"></p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="27%" height="14">
                <p align="right">Этаж</p>
            </td>
            <td width="70%" height="14" align="left">
                <p><input type="text" name="h_et" size="9"></p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="27%" height="11">
                <p align="right">Домофон</p>
            </td>
            <td width="70%" height="11" align="left">
                <p><input type="text" name="h_kod" size="9"></p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="27%">Примечание</td>
            <td width="70%" align="left"><textarea name="other" rows="2"></textarea></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td width="633" colspan="2">
                <p align="center"><input type="submit" name="save" value="Сохранить"></p>
            </td>
        </tr>

    </table>
</form>
```

search.css

```css
 .search{
    position:relative;
}

.search_result{
    margin: 0 0 0 40px;
    background: #FFF;
    border: 0px #ccc solid;
    width: 255px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    max-height:255px;
    overflow-y:scroll;
    display:none;
}

.search_result li{
    list-style: none;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    margin: 0 0 0 -40px;
    border-bottom: 1px #ccc solid;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition:0.3s;

}

.search_result li:hover{
    background: #F9FF00;
}
```

tabl.css

```css
table {
font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", Sans-Serif;
font-size: 14px;
border-radius: 10px;
border-spacing: 0;
text-align: center;
}
th {
background: #BCEBDD;
color: white;
text-shadow: 0 1px 1px #2D2020;
padding: 10px 20px;
}
th, td {
border-style: solid;
border-width: 0 1px 1px 0;
border-color: white;
}
th:first-child, td:first-child {
text-align: left;
}
th:first-child {
border-top-left-radius: 10px;
}
th:last-child {
border-top-right-radius: 10px;
border-right: none;
}
td {
padding: 3px 10px;
background: #F8E391;
}
tr:last-child td:first-child {
border-radius: 0 0 0 10px;
}
tr:last-child td:last-child {
border-radius: 0 0 10px 0;
}
tr td:last-child {
border-right: none;
}
```

Comment: "селект блокируется" - что это значит?

Comment: вы бы запостили html и javascript как они в конечном результате, было бы понятно

Comment: "блокируется" - значит не могу на него нажать и что-то выбрать, хотя он не подсвечивается как заблокированный, просто тупо не нажимается

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Уберите строчку

```
$(".car").attr("disabled","");
```

```js
var test = {
  honda: "<select><option value='civic'>Civic</option><option value='accord'>Accord</option></select>",
  toyota: "<select><option value='corolla'>Corolla</option><option value='camry'>Camry</option></select>"
};

$('.car').change(function(){
  
  var brand = this.value;
  setTimeout(function() {
    var data = test[brand];
    $(".car_search_result").html(data);
  }, 300);
  
  //return false;  
  //$(".car").attr("disabled","");

  /*$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: "findcar.php", //Путь к обработчику
    data: {'car_referal':this.value},
    response: 'html',
    success: function(data){
      $(".car_search_result").html(data);
    }
  });*/
});
$('.car').change();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<select class="car" size="1">
  <option value="honda">Honda</option>
  <option value="toyota">Toyota</option>
</select>
</div>

<div class="car_search_result">
</div>
```

Comment: Я прошу прощения за наглость, но прошу объяснить, как использовать данную конструкцию для обработки удаленно, или мне надо загонять все модели в var test? их 2500... я только учусь, программа для собственных нужд, с php у меня все проще, а вот jquery дается сложно...

Comment: @Dimastik86 нет, переменная `test` использована для имитации асинхронного запроса данных. Вам нужно убрать блок кода с `setTimeout` и раскомментировать `$.ajax`.

Answer (score 0):

СПАСИБО, это работает!

```js
<div>
<select class="car" size="1" name="car_referal">
  <option value="1">Honda</option>
  <option value="33">Toyota</option>
</select>
</div>

<script>  
$('.car').change(function(){


  $.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: "findcar.php", //Путь к обработчику
    data: {'car_referal':this.value},
    response: 'html',
    success: function(data){
      $(".car_search_result").html(data);
    }
  });
});
$('.car').change(); 
</script>  



<div class="car_search_result"></div>
```